# Why does installing TensorFlow require google-auth?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I'm trying to install TensorFlow through conda and I noticed a couple other packages that it wanted to install:

```
google-auth        pkgs/main/noarch::google-auth-1.21.0-py_0
google-auth-oauth~ pkgs/main/noarch::google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1-py_2
```

This seems a bit strange -- why is google-auth required for TensorFlow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow supports running training and inference on Google Cloud, and google-auth is a dependency for that support